# ViewPager instantiates the same fragment multiple times, recyclerView adapter gets messed up

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview

My viewpager uses the same fragment with a recycler view to show lists that are downloaded from the internet based on the position of the viewpager. When everything is first started everything loads correctly.  But when I scroll the recycler view the info is loading from the second page.

my constructor for the recycler adapter

```
//Constructor
public FeedAdapter(List<Feed> feed, Context ctx, Activity activity){
    mFeed = feed;
    context = ctx;
    try{
        mListener = (OnAdapterInteractionListener) activity;
    }catch (ClassCastException e){
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement OnAdapterInteraction");
    }
}
```

and my bindview

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final FeedAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int i) {
    holder.mItem = mFeed.get(i);
    holder.mTitle = holder.mItem.mTitle;
    holder.mImageLink = holder.mItem.mImageLink;
    holder.mDescription = holder.mItem.mDescription;

    //set default image and title text to show if image doesn't exist or hasn't downloaded yet
    holder.ivCardImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.rhaa);
    holder.tvTitle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    holder.tvTitle.setText(holder.mTitle);
    holder.tvDescription.setText(holder.mDescription);
...}
```

and the call from the fragment:

```
mAdapter = new FeedAdapter(feed, context, activity);
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Feed is a custom class that stores all the info for the downloaded items.  Before setting up the viewpager and having the tabs selected from a nav drawer everything worked fine so I know the problem lies with the viewpager I just dont know how to fix it.

Comment: I feel like a dummy.  I figured it out.  mFeed in my adapter was static and when I changed it, everything works correctly.